# Number of solutions for an equation with constraints on each variable in the equation

Tags: combinatorics, integer-partitions

I have to find the number of solutions for: $$x_1 + x_2 + x_3 + x_4 = 42$$
when given:
$$ (I)  12 <= x_1 <=13 $$
$$ (II) 3 <= x_2 <= 6 $$
$$ (III) 11 <= x_3 <= 18 $$
$$ (IV) 6 <= x_4 <= 10 $$

What I did so far, is define:
$$ y_1 = x_1 - 12 $$
$$ y_2 = x_2 - 3 $$
$$ y_3 = x_3 - 11 $$
$$ y_4 = x_4 - 6 $$

Thus we get:
$$ y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 10 $$
where
$$ 0 <= y_1 <= 1 $$
$$ 0 <= y_2 <= 3 $$
$$ 0 <= y_3 <= 7 $$
$$ 0 <= y_4 <= 4 $$

now I defined:
$\text{S = all solutions to}$ $y_1 + y_2 + y_3 + y_4 = 20$
$\text{where all}$ $y_i >=0$ $\text{without the upper limitation}$

and I know I have to subtract the rest of the cases, when $y_1 is >1$ and $y_2 is >3$ etc... but how do I count all those side cases that I should subtract?

Comment: Note that you can use "\leq" for "<=" or "\geq" for ">=".

Comment: Are the $x_i$ integral?

Comment: An integer*, yes.

Answer (score 1):

For the newer information on question, since $x_i$ are integral(which is same as saying that they are integers):

The answer will be coefficient of $x^{10}$ in the following expansion:

$$
\begin{align}
f(x) &= (x^0 + x^1)(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3)(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7)(x^0 + x^1 + x^2 + x^3 + x^4) \\
&= (1 + x)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4)(1 + x + x^2 + x^3 + x^4 + x^5 + x^6 + x^7)
\end{align}
$$

Comment: im sorry. original is =42. my mistake

Comment: What if I give y1 "2" because I know it is at least 2, then calculate A1 (the number of solutions when y1 > 1) and etc? would that solve it and give me the size of each Ai?

Comment: you may have interests in this too: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/751167/counting-problem-very-interesting-modular-n-algebraic-eqs-for-combinatorics?lq=1